# Jtable cellrenderer doesnt change backgroun of integer value

Tags: java, jtable, cell, renderer, lf

I created cellrenderer class for change my rows background.
if row's(rate%)colums value is something i try to change background of row.
But when i try it. Renderer only change non-Integer colums' background.

Here is my renderer.

```
public class hucreRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    Color orginal=Color.white;      
    @Override
 public Component 
       getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                             boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component cell = 
                  super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                         table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

             int value;
              try {
                    //10th column is a 'rate' column
                    v=Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(
                          table.convertRowIndexToView(row), 10).toString());

              }catch(Exception e){value=1000;}

                     if(value<100){     

                            cell.setBackground(Color.red);

                     else{
                cell.setBackground(orginal);
                  }

        return cell;
    }


}
```

and Here is Table Inıt.

```
 String col[] = {"ID","AD","GRUP", "ADET", "Kritik","TELEFON", "TEDARİKÇİ", "ALIŞ", "SATIŞ", "ADRES","RATE(%)"};

urunTablo.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][], col) {
        Class[] types = 
{ Integer.class, String.class,String.class,Integer.class,Integer.class,String.class,String.class,Integer.class,Integer.class,String.class,Integer.class };


DefaultTableModel t =(DefaultTableModel)urunTablo.getModel();
t.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
t.setColumnIdentifiers(col);


for(Urun u:urunler){     
        int r=new Integer(u.getRate());
        Object row[]={
        new Integer( u.getKod()),
        u.getAd(),
        u.getGrup(),
        new Integer( u.getAdet()),
        new Integer(u.getKritikAdet()),
        u.getTelefon(),
        u.getTedarikci(),
        new Integer( u.getAlis()),
        new Integer( u.getSatis()),
        u.getAdres(), r};

        t.addRow(row);


    }
```

And here is result.
[image: Example]

and intresting thing is. if i use Nimbus look and feel theme i dont come across whit this problem. 
[image: nimbus example]

and there is a code for nimbus. i use this in main method of this dialog

```
 try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
//and the catchs...
```

Thank a lot alredy now.
have a nice day.

Edit:default cell renderer doesnt work for cells which is hold Integer.class.
Thats the main problem.

Comment: One error not related to your case: `v=Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToView(row), 10).toString());` >> **Wrong**. Should be: `v=Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 10).toString());`

Comment: Another error. If you directly modify the `DefaultTableModel`'s `dataVector` by calling `removeAllElements` on it, you should call [`fireTableDataChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29) on the model right after that.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the cell renderers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reseach and test :) finally i found the problem.
Problem is setting the tables default renderer style

I was using this type before(Ex code)

```
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new MyDefaultCellRenderer());
```

and this is getting object.class to String.class (in Default)(cause DefaultCellRenderer xD)
and the renderer just work on String cells

And i set my renderer again like this

```
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class,new MyDefaultCellRenderer());
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class,new MyDefaultCellRenderer());
```

Now this is can work for Integer and String cells

Working and Metal! :)
[image]

So u gonna say what about the Look and feel stuff

I think in Nimbus LAF `setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new MyDefaultCellRenderer())` get all type of Object.
Other LAF's doesnt.

Thanks a lot guys. If you have a extra thought about that please leave comment below. 
Have a easy work :)

Comment: That's what I suspected, something to with setting the renderers. GJ ;-). Since you've answered your own question and the problem is solved you should check the ✔ next to your answer.

Comment: yes you're right but i answered my question too early and system doesnt allow me to check my own question. Thanks a lot.